# It it possible to express an always-true function using product of sums in boolean algebra?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Consider such boolean function:
$$f(x,y,z) = 1$$
It is easy, but a trifle tedious, to express this function using the sum of products. However, let's say that we are asked to express it using the product of sums. 
Is this even possible?

Comment: Does an empty product count?

Comment: Every Boolean function has both disjunctive and conjunctive form.

Comment: And so what is the correct answer? $f(x, y, z) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-empty conjunctive form containing all three variables is $$f(x,y,z)=1=(x+\neg{x})(y+\neg y)(z+\neg z)$$

Comment: Why do you need the CNF to contain all three variables?

Comment: It is one of possible forms.

Answer (score 2):

$x + \lnot x$ is both a sum of products (disjunctive normal form) and a product of sums (conjunctive normal form) for the identically true function on any number of propositional variables.